# GRUB doesn't boot copied Linux install

Tags: linux, debian, lvm, grub, luks

I copied a Linux installation from one partition to another partition on a different drive. I did this from a live usb and omitted dev, /proc and /sys. I ran update-grub from the original install, it found the copy installment and created an entry. The entry looks fine. I edited the new /etc/fstab as a last step by commenting out old stuff and writing new stuff using the new UUIDs.

The original install is Debian installed onto LVM on LUKS. It is a non encrypted boot partition and a LUKS partition which holds a swap partition and a root partition via LVM. The new partition is just one single unencrypted partition.

However, when I try to boot the new GRUB entry, it always loads the old version from the old partition, even when the UUIDs in the grub.cfg are definitely the right ones. I am always asked to unlock the old partition while booting from the new one, and when I do that and let it boot through, only the old partition is mounted, not the new one.

Comment: How did you perform the copy?

Comment: I believe (some) contents of `/etc/fstab` are included in the initial ram disk.  Have you tried calling `update-initramfs` https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/initramfs-tools/update-initramfs.8.en.html.  At least there is a chicken and egg problem where the kernel needs to know the partition containing /etc/fstab before it has mounted that partition.

Comment: You may also be missing a `grub-install` in there somewhere.

Comment: update-initramfs did the trick! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Chrooting into the new copied install and running update-initramfs did the trick.